# Batch Error In Number Guesser

Tags: batch-file, random, numbers

I was creating a simple random number guesser in batch but I got an error in my code and don't know what it is please help. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
title Number Guesser
:menu
echo ------------------
echo   Number Guesser
echo ------------------
echo 1. Easy
echo 2. Medium
echo 3. Hard
echo 4. Exit
set /p dif=Select difficulty number:
if %dif% == 1 goto easygen
if %dif% == 2 goto medgen
if %dif% == 3 goto hardgen
if %dif% == 4 exit
goto menu


:easygen
set /a num=%random%
if %num% gtr 20 goto gen
cls
goto play

:medgen
set /a num=%random%
if %num% gtr 50 goto gen
cls
goto play

:hardgen
set /a num=%random%
if %num% gtr 100 goto gen
cls
goto play


:play
set /p guess=Guess:
if %guess% == %num% goto win
if %guess% gtr %num% echo Lower!
if %guess% lss %num% echo Higher!

:win
cls
echo Well Done
echo 1. Play again!
echo 2. Quit
set /p cmd=What do you want to do:
if %cmd% == 1 goto menu
if %cmd% == 2 exit
```

I get the error once I choose the difficulty (dif) I have no idea what isn't working. It just closes.

Comment: where is your label `:gen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up cmd then navigate to the file and run it, instead of double clicking the batch file, you'll see an error.

```
The system cannot find the batch label specified - gen
```

Like the other commenter said, you don't have `:gen` defined. It says `goto gen`, but `gen` doesn't exist, so it freaks out and closes.